# Templated template specialization for template argument

Tags: c++, c++11

Say you have the following:

```cpp
SomeType *x;
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<SomeType>> v;
```

And you want to call a function like this:

```cpp
do_something(v.begin(), v.end(), x);
```

Say `do_something` is templated, and you want to make a specialization for the case of `container<unique_ptr<T>>`. Even if not for specialization, let's simply say we want to have the `container` templatized but always assuming inside it is a `unique_ptr`.

I tried the following:

```cpp
template<template <typename X, typename Y> class C, typename T, typename Allocator>
inline int do_something(typename C<std::unique_ptr<T>, Allocator>::iterator first,
                        typename C<std::unique_ptr<T>, Allocator>::iterator last,
                        const T* value)
{ ... }
```

But g++, clang and cl.exe all fail to deduce the type of `C`. What's ambiguous here? And what can I do about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anything to the left of `::` is a non-deduced context.

Here's something that will allow your function to be called on any iterator whose `value_type` is a `std::unique_ptr`.

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
struct is_unique_ptr : public std::false_type {};
template <typename T, typename D>
struct is_unique_ptr<std::unique_ptr<T,D>> : public std::true_type {};

template <typename Iter, typename T>
auto do_something(Iter first, Iter last, const T* value) ->
std::enable_if_t<is_unique_ptr<typename std::iterator_traits<Iter>::value_type>
                 ::value, int>
{ ... }
```

Note this now includes not just `Container::iterator` but `Container::reverse_iterator` and any other "wrapper" iterator with the same `value_type`.  (But not `Container::const_iterator`.)